# How to display string length in winui3 while typing

Tags: .net-6.0, winui-3

I would like to display the length of a string in a textbox while typing. The code below works in WPF but does not in WinUI3. How must I adapt the code below?

```
<TextBox Name="tbInput" Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Input, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=tbInput, Path=Text.Lenght, Mode=OneWay}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `x:Bind`:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{x:Bind tbInput.Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Or bind directly to the source property (assuming the view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`):

```
<TextBox Name="tbInput" Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Input, Mode=TwoWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBlock> 
    <Run Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Input.Length, Mode=OneWay}" />
</TextBlock>
```